# Check value in MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP.

What I want is not much. I just want to place a check on my page which goes to database and check for value 1 or 0. 1 means "enable" so page continues ; and 0 means "disable" and  page dies.

someone suggested the following but it didn't work

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1'");
$user = mysql_query($sql);
echo $user;
if ($user !=="1") {
    echo "You are not the proper user type to view this page";
    die();
  }
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause or a `while...if(equal_to)` loop

Comment: someone sugested some other place$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1'");
$user = mysql_query($sql);
echo $user;
if ($user !=="1") {
 echo "You are not the proper user type to view this page";
    die();
  }

Comment: it's one of the other, why both? that is failing you right there. put that in your question btw. Don't dump code in comments and full code.

Comment: this is failing you btw `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1'"); 
$user = mysql_query($sql);` and you should be getting an error for it. and missing a looping function

Comment: yes my page doesn't continue its stuck on "You are not the proper user type to view this page"

Comment: That's because you have errors and I have outlined them in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `mysql_query()` twice and that alone will cause a syntax error.

You're also not looping over results, so use the following to achieve what you want to do.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1'"; 
$user = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user)){

        if ($row['access'] !=="1") { 
            echo "You are not the proper user type to view this page"; 
            die(); 
        }
        else {
                echo "You are the right type.";
            }

}
```

If your query requires a db connection to the query, you will need to do:

```
$user = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

This assuming a `mysql_` successful connection. However, that API is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and deleted as of PHP 7.0 and note that different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

It's time to step into the 21st century and use either the MySQLi_ or PDO API.

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You may also have to select an actual row (or rows) instead of `SELECT * FROM members`

I.e.:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM members
```

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

---

You can also achieve this with `mysql_num_rows()`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

You might also want to add to the `WHERE` clause:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE access= '1' AND column='x' ");
```